# Insert data to two tables in the same time. h2 database

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I have problem with writing SQL query. I want to insert data to my h2 database.
My application using spring boot with memory h2 database.

My two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ScreeningTime> screeningTime;
    private int screeningRoomId;
}

@Entity
public class ScreeningTime {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private long screeningTime;
}
```

I want to insert data using a SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.MOVIES (TITLE, SCREENING_TIME, SCREENING_ROOM_ID) 
VALUES ('Film1', 1573399800000, 1);
```

My query is wrong, but I do not know how to fix it. Could you help me?

Comment: If you are using `spring-boot` why not JPA?

Comment: I do not know how do it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use spring data jpa

Create Repository in your project. 
help https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

```
ScreeningTime time1=new ScreeningTime ();
time1.setScreeningTime("yourtime");

ScreeningTime time2=new ScreeningTime ();
time2.setScreeningTime("yourtime");

List<ScreeningTime> times=new ArrayList<>();
times.add(time1);
times.add(time2);

Movie m=new Movie();
m.setTitle("Film1");
m.setScreeningRoomId(1);
m.setScreeningTime(times);

repository.save(m);
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. It is another lesson for me. But could you help mi with sql script?

Answer (score 0):

adding for screen time. you can d for movie

```
 @Repository
    public interface ScreeningTime extends CrudRepository<ScreeningTime , Long> {

        @Modifying
        @Query(value = "insert into ScreeningTime (id,screeningTime) VALUES (:id,:screeningTime)", nativeQuery = true)
        @Transactional
        void saveScreen(@Param("id") String id, @Param("screeningTime") Long screeningTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring boot, then you can also just autowire the EntityManager in your service class and use persist method to save your changes. Please make sure to mark your service class method @Transactional. Also, make sure to add spring-data-jpa in the pom.xml file.

@Autowired
EntityManager em;

// add your code here to populate the movie object

em.persist(movie);

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I want to add movieId field to ScreeningTime entity. What should change i your example or entity properties? Should I add some adnotation? or atribute?